# Javascript Unsigned Short Grayscale Images

Tags: javascript, canvas, bufferedimage

I'm encoding a Java BufferedImage with type TYPE_USHORT_GRAY as base64 providing it to a Javascript client via a REST api.

I can clearly inspect the distinct pixels values in the proper range (0 to 65k) on the server-side, but the canvas api seems to only provide rgba pixels, resulting in an unacceptable loss of precision for my use case.

Is it possible for client-side Javascript to read and manipulate the pixel values of (but not display) an unsigned short grayscale image through the canvas or some other api?

Comment: You want to be able to display 16-bit greyscale images in a canvas?

Comment: I want to be able to read the grayscale values in the proper range, because in our case they'll be converted to a different, actual color scheme based on those values, then displayed. I'll see if I can clear that up in my question.

Comment: You may have more luck storing the data [in a `Int16Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int16Array) for processing before sending to a canvas then.

Comment: Oh excellent point,thanks! I'll investigate that and report back.

Comment: I should probably say to use the `UInt16Array` to handle unsigned values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store the pixels in a `Uint16Array` buffer and then read and write the luminance values to an from that. Note that byte-order (network/big-endian vs. little-endian) will matter - a `DataView` can help you with that, or just swap byte-order if incoming buffer is big-endian.

Note also that out-of-range values are getting the modulo treatment so you need to clip them manually (or write using mask 0xffff). Then access each luminance value as an ordinary array using indexes.

However, if you intend to do a lot of processing I would recommend using a floating point buffer instead with normalized values, using either a `Float32Array` or `Float64Array` - the former is faster, the latter more accurate. This will also allow you to push the dynamic range in and out as you want, unless you need to clamp the values for each pass.

To normalize (obvious, but for the record):

```
newLum = oldLum / 0xffff;
```

Tip: to get a more accurate preview, if you need that along the way, is to use the following approach to downscale - in principle for any depth:

```
var inDepth = Math.pow(2, 16) - 1;   // 65535
var outDepth = Math.pow(2, 8) - 1;   // 255
```

then for each luminance value:

```
var r,g,b,a;
r = g = b = (lum * outDepth / inDepth + 0.5)|0;    // or, in this case -
r = g = b = (lum * 0.0038910505836575876 + 0.5)|0;
a = 255;
```

If source uses gamma there will be need to convert gamma to linear before processing, when done, reapply gamma.

You could always do a mask/shift op. but that will not be as accurate.

(Canvas will always use a 8-bit based RGBA buffer).

Answer (score 0):

For ease of implementation, we decided to re-encode the image to a set of RGB values in a manner that captures the full range of values we need: basically, treating each pixel as a 3-digit base 256 number.

This kind of sidesteps the question, so I'll accept Ken Fyrstenberg's answer regardless.